# AudioKit: How to tap the same input for multiple uses (AudioKitUI + Speech Recognition)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, audiokit, avaudioengine

I would like to be able to use one of `AudioKitUI`'s components `FFTView` in conjunction with the input node to visually show the node input as well as perform Speech Recognition.

Per `BaseTap.swift` notes about taps (line 65):

```
// a node can only have one tap at a time installed on it
// make sure any previous tap is removed.
// We're making the assumption that the previous tap (if any)
// was installed on the same bus as our bus var.
```

If a node can only have one tap, how can we use the `AudioKitUI` components in conjunction with the actual data of those taps?

I am (successfully) tapping the input to do speech recognition as such:

`audioManager.mic.avAudioNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)`

however when I try to install the tap for recondition and then use `FFTView`, the app crashes with `error -10868`. This makes sense considering I can only have one tap installed, but conceptionally I don't understand how to get around this limitation. I know and have seen apps that tap an audio input, display that data, as well as process the data simultaneously. Any guidance would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a series of mixers inline and do what you need to each of them. Tap each one a maximum of once.